# Консольная псевдографика в линуксе

Tags: c++, linux, linux-mint

В windows есть библиотека для консольной графики: windows. h. Есть ли что-нибудь похожее в линуксе? Что можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Ой, а можно с этого места - **библиотека для консольной графики: windows.h** - подробнее?

Comment: @Harry хех, это жестоко)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Linux есть замечательная библиотека ncurses, предназначенная для управления вводом-выводом на терминал. Помимо всего прочего позволяет отображать нужные символы в нужном месте экрана, устанавливать цвет символа и/или фона, работать с окнами в текстовом режиме.

Comment: Хочется добавить, что она не только под линуксом есть, есть еще и аналог под винду - pdcurses. И при написании кода лучше указывать не ncurses, а просто curses - тогда код легче будет перенести на другую систему.